# How can I use the File Compare tool in Visual Studio to merge changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I've just started to use TFS in Visual Studio and have come across the *Compare Files* feature.  It works great in showing the differences between two local copies of the same file, but how do I merge the changes?

In most file comparison software there is the option to *Copy Left/Right* or *Accept Change* or at the very least to edit the files directly and paste in your own code.

Visual Studio does not seem to offer any of this.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio comare is sadly missing the options to *Copy Left*/*Copy Right*/*Accept Change*.

You should however be able to edit the Right side of a normal compare and the Result part of a Merge compare. Only situation where this is not possible is for solution and project files that you currently have open in the same instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use third-part tool.
I found great even the free version of [**Code Compare**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.CodeCompare) that is both stand alone and integrated VS extension.